# why my multiple if else is not working in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

```js
function myFunction2() {
  var booloo = document.getElementById('texa').value;
  if (!document.getElementById('texa').value) {
    //var res = booloo.lastcharAt(booloo.value);
    console.log("nothing");
  } else if (booloo.substring(booloo.length - 1) == "+" || "-" || "*" || "/") {
    console.log("String Contain Operator at last");
  } else if (booloo.substring(booloo.length - 1) == "0" || "1" || "2" || "3" || "4" || "5" || "6" || "7" || "8" || "9") {
    console.log("String contain Operand at last");
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <input types="text" id="texa">
  <button onclick="myFunction2()">Try it</button>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm trying to use multiple if else blocks in my code but at third block("String contain Operand at last") this is not working only remaining two blocks are working perfect. my objectives are if user type value like e.g 10+ value then it goes in second block that operator contain at last. and if suppose user type 10+2 then it must goes into third block like ("contain Operand at last") but the problem is it does not goes into third block.

Comment: syntax error in comparison

Answer (score 7):

That is not how a comparison works.

```
if(booloo.substring(booloo.length - 1) == "+" || "-" || "*" || "/")
```

should be written as

```
if(booloo.substring(booloo.length - 1) == "+" 
   || booloo.substring(booloo.length - 1) == "-" 
   || booloo.substring(booloo.length - 1) == "*" 
   || booloo.substring(booloo.length - 1) == "/")
```

---

Your existing code would be evaluated like this:

- check if booloo.substring(booloo.length - 1) == "+"
- Check if "-" (*always evals to true, rest of statement would not be tested but I wrote it out anyway*)
- check if "*" (*also always evals to true*)
- check if "/" (*also always evals to true*)

Answer (score 1):

I would use an array of operands to check the last character against and a ternary operator to differentiate the two outcomes if there is a value in the textbox.

```js
function myFunction2() {
  var booloo = document.getElementById('texa').value;
  
  if (!document.getElementById('texa').value) {
    //var res = booloo.lastcharAt(booloo.value);
    console.log("nothing");
  } else {
  var operands=["+", "-", "*","/"];
  var lastChar= operands.indexOf(booloo.substring(booloo.length - 1)) ==-1 ? "Operator" : "Operand";
  
  console.log("String contains " + lastChar + " at last")
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <input types="text" id="texa">
  <button onclick="myFunction2()">Try it</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare to multiple values as you are trying to do.

You either have to write it out

```
booloo.substring(booloo.length - 1) == "+" || 
booloo.substring(booloo.length - 1) == "-" ||
// ...
```

Or create an array and check for indexOf()

```
var check1 = ['+','-','*','/'];
if (check1.indexOf(booloo.substring(booloo.length - 1) > -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a single character and check it agains a string for the index.

```js
function myFunction2() {
    var booloo = document.getElementById('texa').value;
    if (!document.getElementById('texa').value) {
        //var res = booloo.lastcharAt(booloo.value);
        console.log("nothing");
    } else if ('+-*/'.indexOf(booloo[booloo.length - 1]) !== -1) {
        console.log("String Contain Operator at last");
    } else if ('0123456789'.indexOf(booloo[booloo.length - 1]) !== -1) {
        console.log("String contain Operand at last");
    }
}
```

```html
<input types="text" id="texa"> <button onclick="myFunction2()">Try it</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better way of doing it with Regular Expression.

```js
function myFunction2() {
  var booloo = document.getElementById('texa').value;
  var arr = [];
  if (!booloo) {
    console.log("nothing");
  } else {
    arr = booloo.split(/[+|-|*|\/]/);
    console.log(arr);

    if (arr[arr.length - 1] == "") {
      console.log("String Contain Operator at last");
    } else {
      console.log("String contain Operand at last");
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <input types="text" id="texa">
  <button onclick="myFunction2()">Try it</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your conditional statement is wrong defined. Rather than for checking for `booloo.substring(booloo.length - 1) == "+"` or `"-" || "*" || "/"` is logical `true` you should check for char occurrence in a string as following:

```js
function myFunction2() {
  var booloo = document.getElementById('texa').value;
  
  if (!document.getElementById('texa').value) {
    console.log("nothing");
    return; // terminate function execution
  }

  var char = booloo.substring(booloo.length - 1);

  if (["+", "-", "*", "/"].indexOf(char) !== -1) {
      console.log("String Contain Operator at last");
  }

  else if (["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"].indexOf(char) !== -1) {
      console.log("String contain Operand at last");
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <input types="text" id="texa">
  <button onclick="myFunction2()">Try it</button>
</body>

</html>
```